# Why doesn't my battery pack run a 12 V lamp very long?

Tags: batteries, voltage-regulator, dc-dc-converter, boost, ampere-hour

I am new to this forum. While I have been experimenting with electronics for years, I guess I am still a novice. Please help me understand why my battery pack doesn't run a 12 V LED lamp very long.

I have 8 AA rechargeable, fully charged batteries connected in series. They say they can deliver 1.2 V and 2000 mAh. I know that voltage drops as the batteries are discharged, so decided I needed a boost converter module to deliver smooth 12 V output.

The input meter on the booster shows 9.89 V which is about what I would expect with no load. As soon as I turn on the bulb the voltage drops to 6.43 V.  The output meter shows I am getting 12 V out and I am drawing 0.85 A. I believe that sounds about right because it is a 10 W, 12 V LED bulb.

I calculated that the light should burn for about 1.9 hours (I originally, incorrectly stated 19 hours).  I know there is resistance that I don't how to measure, so I was ready to accept 20-25% reduction.

But the lamp burns for only about 5 minutes.

Comment: What happens to the battery voltage during these 5 minutes? Does it drop further? Do the batteries get warm? And what brand of batteries are these?

Comment: Datasheet for the boost converter, batteries, and LED bulb? Also, you are "drawing 0.85 Ah" -- shouldn't that be amps, not amp-hours?

Comment: Measure the voltage across each cell with the lamp on, and throw away any cell producing < 1V under load. Also, 1.2V * 2Ah = 2.4Wh, *8 = 19.2Wh, so you can't expect to get 190Wh out of them.

Comment: Are the batteries new? In good condition or old?

Comment: How did you end up with 19 hours, with a battery of 2 Ah and lamp needing almost 1A?

Comment: Do your calculations again, 1 AA contains 1.2V * 2000mAh = 2.4Wh, 8 AA contains 2.4Wh * 8 = 19.2 Wh, You are using a 10W led light, which consumes 10Wh every hour, so in theory, they only last 2 hours, not 19 hours

Comment: Wow, I don't know how I was off by a factor of 10x.   Yes, I now see that 19.2 was Wh and so my light should only run for 1.9 hours.

Comment: Take a look at the input current to your converter.  That voltage drop looks like it might be the result of a problem there.

Comment: The batteries were Amazon Basics Rechargeable.     I also have some brand new Energizer Recharge Plus.   I am going to test again with those.

Comment: Thank you all for your help.  I am going to test again and make more detailed notes of what all happens.

Comment: I thought AA batteries were really only good up to about 50 mA. Your internal resistance is probably going way up under a load that high, probably to the point where the battery voltage goes below the minimum input of the boost converter.

Comment: Amazon basics rechargeable batteries seem to be NiMH which are fairly low resistance.  These Panasonic batteries:
https://eu.industrial.panasonic.com/sites/default/pidseu/files/downloads/files/id_ni-mh_1104_e.pdf
have curves up to 3C and OP is discharging at ~1C.  The drop to 0.8V/cell under load could indicate some sort of overcurrent situation.

Comment: @Ryan I have used alkaline AA batteries at much higher current levels. They can do fine at 200 or 300 mA. NiMH batteries can support even more current with less droop, although they also have lower open-circuit voltage. You can find the discharge curves online from duracell, energizer, etc. Also, a lot of highly competent hobbyists have published discharge curves at various currents for all popular battery brands.

Comment: It looks like there is some back-and-forth editing going on. But I am pretty sure that the OP didn't mean 0.85 Ah as that makes no sense in context. It is probably supposed to be 0.85 A. Maybe the OP can review the edits and decide which ones to keep.

Comment: Better notes this time:  Brand new Energizer Recharge Plus AA, Qty 8 in series, fully charged, 1.2V, 2300mAh, NiMH;  DZS Elec DC-DC Buck Boost Converter Module 5.5-30V 12v to 0.5-30V 5v 24v;  Globe-Electric 12v 10w lamp

--- At no load:  10.82V in, 12V out
--- At start of load:  7.48V in, 11.93V out, 0.817A
--- 2min:  7.15V in, 11.88V out, 0.825A
--- 3m:  7.08V in, 11.88V out, 0.825A
--- 4m:  7.00V in, 11.88V out, 0.825A
--- 5m:  6.96V in, 11.88V out, 0.825A
--- 6m:  6.90V in, 11.87V out, 0.825A
--- 7m:  6.94V in, 11.86V out, 0.825A
--- 7:30m:  lamp goes out, load off, 9.88V in

Comment: This time I noticed one of the terminals on the battery holder was very hot.  Did not notice that before.

Comment: If the terminals on the battery holder are very hot, that could explain the excessive voltage drop. The helical coil spring terminals are terrible for high current applications. They are often made of spring steel, which is a very poor conductor, and their narrow cross section plus long current path add up to very high resistance.

Comment: It might be a good idea to add a picture of your setup. A lot of times people notice issues in a picture that are not mentioned in the text of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As soon as I turn on the bulb the voltage drops to 6.43 V

Something is terribly wrong. That is only 0.8 Volts per cell. Much too low. Try to measure the input current. Maybe the boost is not operating properly for some reason and is consuming vast amounts of input current (although it would be getting hot if that were the case).

Also, consider using 10 AA batteries in series and powering the lamp directly. You will probably have much better results.

Each cell has something like 2 Watt-hours of energy in it. A little more actually. So that means 8 cells have 16-20 Watt-hours. So your calculation of expected battery life appears to be a good ballpark number. I would guesstimate about 1.5 hours to allow for various normal expected losses.

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, I made a 10x error in my calculation.   I will try your suggestion of using 10 in series without the booster.

Comment: Just saw your comment about the battery terminals getting hot. That is definitely a problem you should fix. Maybe that is the biggest problem.

Comment: Thank you, I will get a better quality battery pack and see if that solves it.

Answer (score 0):

Your AA rechargeable cells must be very old, not fully charged or very cheap to have their voltage per cell drop to only 6.43V/8= 0.8V.

A Name-brand AA Ni-MH rechargeable cell can supply 1A for almost 1 hour when its 1.4V has dropped to 1.1V.
A name-brand AA alkaline battery can supply 1A for half an hour when its 1.5V has dropped to 1.25V.
A very cheap no-name-brand AA "Super" heavy duty battery from China has trouble producing more than 50mA.

Comment: They were brand new fully charged.    On my first test I used Amazon Basics Recharge NiMH, 1.2V, 2000mAh.  On my second test I used brand new fully charged Energizer Recharge Plus, NiMh, 1.2V, 2300mAh.

Answer (score 0):

You measured .85A at 12V.  With an input of around 10 volts, the current draw would be right around 1A.  You say the cells are 2 Amp-Hour.  With those numbers I'd say the most run time you would get is 2 hours.

Comment: Yes, thank you.  I made a 10x error in my calculation.